# Automatically Create Concrete Commands

Tags: c++, design-patterns

Does anyone know of a good way to automatically create concrete commands for the GoF Command Pattern?

(I have not been able to find anything on the Net that addresses this particular "convenience.")

As of now, I plan to nest the class definitions in the main class and then use a macro (something like what is shown below) to create the 100's of declarations and instantiations.   (Of course, the definition of execute() will have to be created for each, but the declaration of the class and instantiation of the class is the part that I would like to automate or better streamline somehow.)

```
#define CREATE_CONCRETE_CLASS(x) \
    class x##ConcreteCmd :  public AbstractCommand \
    {\
       public:\
     \
     \
        void execute();\
      \
    };\
   \
  x##ConcreteCmd x##ConcreteCmdInst;
```

The above macro would then be used to include a series of these in an include file and include it to create the nested classes and associated instantiations thereof as in:

```
CREATE_CONCRETE_CLASS(cmd1)
CREATE_CONCRETE_CLASS(cmd2)
.
.
.
```

Is there a cleaner way to create these concrete command class definitions in a concise format differentiated by only their command names?

Comment: What about using a template class (e.g. a [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern)) instead of a macro?

Comment: Maybe.   I will have to think about that a bit.

Comment: I think there is some value in using a template class instead of a macro.   I am not sure if CRTP is indicated yet (still need to think about that part).   Would CRTP be related to the automated creation o f the instance: x##ConcreteCmd x##ConcreteCmdInst ?    Is your suggestion to replace the class portion of the macro with the template, and encapsulate that in a macro that uses the template and  then adds the instantiation?

Comment: Are you asking how to _create_ these classes? If so, just use `std::function<void()>`.  Or, are you asking how to register them with some other entity, along with a useful name?

Comment: In the example included above, I am doing both at the same time.  The  second code sample is in an include file that is called to create nested classes in a parent class.   The last line of the macro in the first code sample also instantiates an instance of the concrete command, so it is somewhat nice and tidy.   As mentioned in the earlier comment, a portion of the macro could be replaced by a template class.   Thank you for suggesting std::function.   I had not considered that previously. Also, the entire pattern could be replaced by a jump table, but that is a bit tangential.